# Plotting specgram with matplotlib for multiple arrays

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have the values like this and I would like to plot the spectrogram for these values and I am using the following code and getting an error :     pad_xextent = (NFFT-noverlap) / Fs / 2
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'int' and 'NoneType'

```
[[ 0.         35.34028168 36.09317546 20.88056919 35.65257548 36.39835111
  29.89568243 34.94770207 36.03834023 36.51054007]
 [35.34028168  0.         36.31999524 34.455879   35.46084735 35.99851703
  35.23984878 35.98339627 35.87905754 36.08155069]
 [36.09317546 36.31999524  0.         35.68280382 36.11374003 35.30407355
  35.97087692 36.20023994 35.75066441 36.01957597]
 [20.88056919 34.455879   35.68280382  0.         24.76405132 36.31596819
  30.47948816 36.27410762 36.30076717 35.76478691]
 [35.65257548 35.46084735 36.11374003 24.76405132  0.         36.17666549
  29.51602419 36.33520073 36.21391866 36.19753349]
 [36.39835111 35.99851703 35.30407355 36.31596819 36.17666549  0.
  36.22994817 36.32591538 36.05558867 36.20784639]
 [29.89568243 35.23984878 35.97087692 30.47948816 29.51602419 36.22994817
   0.         36.14432269 36.19523145 35.40707841]
 [34.94770207 35.98339627 36.20023994 36.27410762 36.33520073 36.32591538
  36.14432269  0.         36.05260398 36.38549268]
 [36.03834023 35.87905754 35.75066441 36.30076717 36.21391866 36.05558867
  36.19523145 36.05260398  0.         35.92987568]
 [36.51054007 36.08155069 36.01957597 35.76478691 36.19753349 36.20784639
  35.40707841 36.38549268 35.92987568  0.        ]]


    print(values)
    plt.specgram(values)
    plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look into the documentation of [specgram](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.specgram.html?highlight=specgram#matplotlib.pyplot.specgram), you will find that it only takes 1D arrays as input.
Assuming that you want the spectrogram of the data row wise, I'd try the following (using some random data for show)

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.subplots(3, 1, sharex=True)
data = np.random.rand(3, 25600)
for i, row in enumerate(data):
    ax[i].specgram(row)
plt.show()
```

This will (as a default) slice 256 wide parts out of every row, and calculate the FFT with the (default) overlap of 128 data points to neighboring chunks. The corresponding x-axis is then the frequency.
[image]

You'll certainly need to at least adjust the value of `NFFT`, `noverlap` and `window` to your use case.